# Are animations handled by Unity animator determinism?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, non-deterministic

I could not found anywhere in Unity documentation if the animations are determinism or not. I think it is but need to be sure. thanks

Comment: Animations are keyframed properties so one should be able to expect that at the same time key they always have the same values ... what do you mean by `determinism` (or deterministic)? Do you have a specific usecase?

Comment: "expect that at the same time key they always have the same values" that's exactly what I am looking for. I am using multi-instance of my unity app to do multi-screen.

Comment: Why not simply render to multiple screens(displays) then?

Comment: It is not the point (I am working with CAVE), but if you say it is determinism it's good for me :)

Comment: Cave? Aren't these as well simply multiple displays?

Comment: @derHugo I think each screen is rendered by a standalone process. If that is the case, I *think* that if you set the animator's `updateMode` to `AnimatorUpdateMode.AnimatePhysics`, and ensure that you cap your frame rate and NEVER go below it on any instance; it should be good enough for achieving a seamless VR experience. I.E. If any instance fails to keep up rendering @ 144hz (for example), this might cause the player to feel some diziness or unease.